# Collision Detection between two objects (PyGame)

Tags: python

I'm creating a game where you have to jump over logs to stay alive. I've gone as far as creating all the animation. However, I am having trouble with collision detection between the logs and the player. I created the code without using sprites or rectangles and I'm hoping to keep it that way.

Basically, is there a way to detect a collision between two objects/images without the need for rectangles? If there isn't, is there a way to fix my code without changing too much?

Here are the two objects:

```
class player():
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 250
            self.y = 202
            self.ani_speed_init = 10
            self.ani_speed = self.ani_speed_init
            self.ani = Tod
            self.ani_pos = 0
            self.ani_max = len(self.ani) - 2
            self.img = self.ani[0]

class log_roll():
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 23
            self.y = 116
            self.ani = Log_roll
            self.pos = 0
            self.pos_max = len(self.ani) - 1
            self.img = self.ani[0]
            self.counter = 0
```

- Tod and Log_roll refer to lists that hold images

Comment: I dont think you can, and i recommend using sprites, that would actually shorten your code btw!!

Comment: if you would like i can answer your question and provide an example, but tell me if you would like to use sprites first...